# global scope is not getting all variable values from function to another

Tags: php, function, scope

i have this function

```
function one(){
 query here fetching data without any errors
 global $picture;
 global $roomnum;   
 $roomnum=$row['room_num'];
 $picture=$row['picture'];
 echo $picture."<br>".$roomnum;
}
function two(){
 global $picture;
 global $roomnum;
 echo $picture."<br>".$roomnum;
}
```

the problem is both variables are correct in the first function while the roomnum echo nothing at all in the second function like it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Declare the global variables outside the functions only once. This is because the code is not executed until the function is called.